# Dynamically creating variables in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < nCounter ; i++)
{
    string dvName = "dv" + i.ToString();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dvName = new DataGridView();
    // other operations will go here..
}
```

As you can guess, what I am trying to do is at `i == 1`, create a `DataGridView` with name `dv1`, and at `i == 2`, create a `DataGridView` with name `dv2`, but I can't.

Visual studio squiggles saying ***"a local variable named dvName is already delared in this scope"*** I also tried the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i <nCounter ; i++)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dv & i = new DataGridView();
    // other operations will go here..
}
```

But VS squiggles again, I hope you understood what I am trying to accomplish. Can anyone suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your are trying to create the variable name dynamically? That's not possible. Why not use an Array or a List (or even a Dictionary)? Or do you want to just set the name of the control?

```
var list = new List<DataGridView>();

for (int i = 1; i <nCounter ; i++)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dvName = new DataGridView();
    dvName.Name = "dv" + i.ToString();
    list.Add(dvName);
    // other operations will go here..
}

foreach (var dv in list)
{    
    ...do something... 
}

DataGridView secondDv = list.Single(dv=>dv.Name == "dv2");
secondDv.DoSomething()
```

Not clear want you want to do...

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is a `Dictionary<int, DataGridView> grids`. Populate it in your for loop (`grids[i] = new DataGridView();`) and then, later, use the required grid (`grids[someCalculatedIndex]`)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try a data structure where you can hold your variables eg dict etc

```
 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView>
          grids = new Dictionary<string,System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView>();

for (int i = 1; i <nCounter ; i++)
{
    grids.Add("dv" + i.ToString(), new DataGridView());            
}

// to work on grid 1
DataGridView grid1 = grids["dv1"];
// so on
```